# problem with the php get function?

Tags: php, jquery, get

i want to pass this paramater `topic` to another page,

p.s. the page is loaded using jquery?

the url:

```
http://localhost/final/home.php#page2?topic=jquery
```

now, i want to echo the the topic on #page2

```
<h3 class="timeline"><?php echo $_GET["topic"]; ?> </h3>
```

but it deosnt echo, any solutions, sorry for the newbiw questions :))

load_page.php

```
<?php
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.php'))
include('pages/page_'.$page.'.php');  // i.e page_2.php

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the php from dataType, and read this [read this about datatypes for ajax requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests)

Answer (score 7):

Your URL needs to be like this:

```
http://localhost/final/home.php?topic=jquery#page2
```

Anything after the hash (`#`) isn't sent by the browser, it's purely *for* the browser, e.g. scrolling to the correct location, a way to do AJAX history, etc...but it's not sent in the request, currently all your server is getting is:

```
http://localhost/final/home.php
```

Which explains why `_GET["topic"]` is empty.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the topic parameter is not echoing on the page, the page is loaded good though

Comment: @pingpong - After you change the order so it's before the `#` it's still not echoing?

Comment: @nick yeh i have changed the order, the page is loading okay expect the echo get part?

Comment: @pingpong - Do you have a test page I can see? Also your question has me a bit worried...does the page literally have a `#` in the file name?

Comment: nope it deosnt pages are in the format `page_2.php` and the jquery syntax is here http://pastie.org/1176477

Comment: How is the Pastie snippet related to the problem you describe? I can see no reference to `home.php` or `topic` :-?

Comment: @pingpong - There's no `topic` being passed in your script...only the `page` parameter is set.

Comment: @nick thanks but more `pages` access this script, i only need to pass topic parameter with this page(page 2), do you have a solution for that? sorry im such a dumbass

Comment: @pingpong - Your `loadPage()` function can look like this: http://pastie.org/1176491 if something doesn't pass a topic parameter, that's fine it'll just be empty.

Comment: thank you @nick, its still not echoing the topic value, i think your solution is right, but its obviously something wrong with the load_php.php, the ajax page, ive put in the the question above! thanks again

Comment: @pingpong - If you're posting you need  `$_POST["topic"];` for the echo, since it's a POST and not a GET happening.

Comment: @nick thanks nick i tried the post, its working but it says undefined!! instead of the value of topic, shall i put the topic value in the link or as an id ?? :)))

Comment: @pingpong - Make sure you're passing the topic into the `loadPage()` function, wherever it comes from, I'm not certain where the topic is coming from or I wouldn't have put a note on that in the update pastie.

Comment: but the topic is coming from the url!! where else could come from!

Comment: @pingpong - I don't understand...what does the URL getting passed into `loadPage()` look like? you're currently only passing the hash.  You could, though a bit hacky use your original format and function (in the pastie), but use `&` instead: `#page2&topic=jquery`, since the `?` isn't correct serialization for a POST.

Comment: i tried that aswell, its not working, im just gonna ask another question, don't worry you have helped enough for today, thank u your a star @nick

Answer (score 0):

To practical effects, a URL ends at `#`. Anything else is not even sent tot he server.

You probably want this:

```
http://localhost/final/home.php?topic=jquery#page2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to do something like this:

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
//Replace the URL in your case with "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

Which will return:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

In your case it would be more like:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => localhost
    [path] => /final/home.php
    [query] => topic=jquery
    [fragment] => page2
)
```